# Rails Server requiring restart to show changes

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, webrick

I'm currently learning Ruby on Rails with the help of the Book "Agile Web Development with Rails", but I have a problem with the first application.

I created the app with 
`rails new depot` 
and generated the scaffold with

```
rails generate scaffold Product \title:string description:text image_url:string price:decimal
```

Then I ran `rake db:migrate`

According to the book I should now be able to create new Products which would then display immediately. 
But when adding a new Product it does not show up when viewing the url `http://localhost:3000/products` or `http://localhost:3000/products.json`, When I view the database file the added products are there.

The added Products show up in the list after I restarted the server.
Does anybody know what I've done wrong?

Using: Rails 3.2.4, Ruby 1.9.3, WEBrick 1.3.1, SQLite 3 and Mac OSX

EDIT: Code generated by the scaffold:

```
   products_controller.rb
      # GET /products
      # GET /products.json
      def index
        @products = Product.all

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # index.html.erb
          format.json { render json: @products }
        end
      end

index.html.erb  
<h1>Listing products</h1>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Image url</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= product.title %></td>
    <td><%= product.description %></td>
    <td><%= product.image_url %></td>
    <td><%= product.price %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', product %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(product) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', product, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />

<%= link_to 'New Product', new_product_path %>
```

Comment: How did you add the product to the table?

Comment: I added it with the standard new product link that is automatically created.

Comment: Can you show us how you render/get our products? I mean you action controller. Is your server started in development mode?

Comment: I added the code, starting the server in development mode with -e development does not change a thing.
Also I dont't think this is a problem with the environment I'm in: When I reload the page the function index should load the products again, but Terminal server output shows it is not loading them again, only once after i restart the server. Displaying a newly inserted row after refreshing the Products page should work in the production environment too.

Comment: Nobody? Why does the controller not query the Database? It always shows ActiveRecord: 0.0ms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll bet your Rails version is 3.2.4? Just update your Rails version to 3.2.5+ and you'll be fine.

It's a regression bug in Rails that happened in 3.2.4. It's been fixed: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/7056079761eba049bbc6108946a1626fe169dbdf